# SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1 and Variable Replacement in SQLFiles. Why doesn't this work anymore?

Tags: yaml, devops

I have recently run into a problem with long running YML / SQL deployment processes i have that is causing me some headaches.

I have a deployment pipeline that sets up customer databases for me.  Part of this is to fill in a bunch of configuration items from a SQL file with variables supplied in my YML pipeline.

here is a very basic example of the YML

```
variables:
  Test: '10'



#test inline SQL Script
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Run Test script on database: $(portalName)'
  inputs:
    AzureSubscription: '$(serviceConnection)'
    AuthenticationType: connectionString
    ConnectionString: '$(connectionString)'
    deployType: InlineSqlTask
    SqlInline: 'insert into dbo.Configuration (Name, Value) values (''Test33'', convert(int,$(Test)))'
    IpDetectionMethod: AutoDetect

#test SQL File
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Run Test script on database: $(portalName)'
  inputs:
    AzureSubscription: '$(serviceConnection)'
    AuthenticationType: connectionString
    ConnectionString: '$(connectionString)'
    deployType: SqlTask
    SqlFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Database/_Resources/TestPipelineSQL.sql'
    IpDetectionMethod: AutoDetect
```

Now if i run this my INLINE SQL Task replaces $(Test) with the YML variable (10).  However the second task does not replace it.

Now before all you gurus start with the "AKShUlLy, this task does NOT replace variables in SQL files" (/s) I must tell you that I do have PROOF that it does (or did, at least) :D .  These scripts are my prepackaged "set up customer" script, have been running for a couple years.

As recent as 2023-03-03 this worked:

Task         : Azure SQL Database deployment
Description  : Deploy an Azure SQL Database using DACPAC or run scripts using SQLCMD
Version      : 1.217.0

Now the new versions (that are not working) are v 1.219.
Task         : Azure SQL Database deployment
Description  : Deploy an Azure SQL Database using DACPAC or run scripts using SQLCMD
Version      : 1.219.0

Where can i find out if something changed ? I know i can use a variable substitution script but i am wondering if something changed? and where i would find that out?

thanks!